# external swf files flash

Tags: actionscript-3, linker, flash, external

I'm trying to link pages together by using swf. I originally used scenes but I heard swf r better so I need help. I have the swf loading but the main menu won't go away. I tried using `alpha=0;` but it's no good.

code:

```
vid1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextPage);

//Create a function for the button click
function nextPage(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("page1.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
loader.load(request);
addChild(loader);

//this.background_mc.alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: how about menu.visible = false; ?

Comment: no i got errors saying undefined, the swf code loads the other pages such as back buttons etc. it very frustrating tearing my hair out!

Comment: well you have to give more information about your project structure - where is the menu what is loaded to what - as now we can only guess:)

Comment: i have a main menu which is named mainmenu.swf, here you can open a srcoll which leads you to other pages by buttons. however when i use the above code to go to page1.swf it loads audio but it is behind the mainmenu.swf.

Comment: and mainmenu.swf is laoded in the same way to the main SWF or mainmenu.swf is the one that loads other pages? - before you will answer in the comment - stop. Edit your question and add more details so someone can help you, ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
    addChildAt(loader, 0);
if your menu is only chlid there.

Or you can set this loader downword by 
    loader.y = 100;
if your menu is on top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code should be somewhat like this:

```
function nextPage(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("page1.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
loader.load(request);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);

//this.background_mc.alpha = 0;
}
function swfLoaded(e:Event){
addChild(e.target.content); /* or e.target, i'm not sure*/
}
```